# Plotting Multiple Items as line graph in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
Date     Allotment  NDII_Mean  NDVI_Mean  RGR_Mean  SATVI_Mean            
1984137   Arnston  -0.053650   0.414868  0.938309    0.332712   
1984185   Arnston   0.074928   0.558329  0.867951    0.334555   
1984249   Arnston  -0.124691   0.352225  1.041513    0.331821   
1985139   Arnston  -0.075537   0.468092  0.929414    0.383750   
1985171   Arnston   0.017400   0.493443  0.889835    0.314717   
1986206   Annex     0.151539   0.626690  0.775202    0.332507   
1986238   Annex     0.142235   0.604764  0.823083    0.303600   
1987241   Annex    -0.005423   0.506760  0.911124    0.338675   
1987257   Annex    -0.058166   0.449052  0.961348    0.336879
```

I want to plot based on allotment, so I will need to use groupby.  So for each Allotment I want the Date on the X-Axis, and all four of the columns with mean in the name shown as lines on the graph and their values on the Y-Axis.  I will then save them as pdf's, although it is not necessary that I do if someone knows another way.  I can plot ONE value using this code (I'll lot NDII_Mean in this example) but I want to plot all four of the columns not just one.  The code I am using is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Stefano/Documents/Hurst_plots.csv')

with PdfPages('C:/Users/Stefano/Documents/Hurst_plots.pdf') as pdf:
   for i, group in df.groupby('Allotment'):

        plt.ylabel('Values')
        plt.figure()

        Hurst_plots=group.plot(x='Date', y='NDII_Mean',title=str(i)).get_figure()
        pdf.savefig(Hurst_plots)
```

This is what one of the plots looks like (different than data shown because I shortened my example table):

[image]

edit:

This works by adding editing this line

```
Hurst_plots=group.plot(x='Date', y=['NDII_Mean', 'RGR_Mean', 'SATVI_Mean', 'SWIR32_Mean'],title=str(i)).get_figure()
```

[image]

but does anyone know how to take the legend outside of the graph completely?

Answer (score 1):

I have had mixed experiences using pandas to make graphics, most of the time I end up pulling the columns out of the dataframe as numpy arrays and using that to plot with matplotlib directly. Personally I feel like I have more control over plots using matplotlib itself for things like styling plots, line colors (often I find myself dynamically generating RGB triplets based on some calculation), and controlling legends! I'd first recommend searching thru the matplotlib documentation, try searching for multi-line plot in matplotlib. It looks like you are trying to plot timeseries. Matplotlib has nice (albeit a little confusing at first) interface for handling dates so once you figure out how things work you can customize to your liking.

Here is a snippet of something I used recently to generate a multi line timeseries plot, note the use of this recently added style feature it makes the plots look very nice. Taken from an ipython notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
%matplotlib inline
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

months = mdates.MonthLocator(range(1,13), bymonthday=1)
monthsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.hold(True)
for year in range(2010,2016):
    vals = dfs[str(year)]['my_awesome_points'].cumsum().values
    adjusted_d_obj = ['2014'+x[4:] for x in dfs[str(year)]['date']]
    date_objs = [dt.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d') for x in adjusted_d_obj]
    dates = [mdates.date2num(x) for x in date_objs]
    #dateints = range(len(dates))
    if year == 2015:    
        ax.plot_date(dates, vals, '-', color=colors[str(year)],                          label=str(year))
    else:
        ax.plot_date(dates,vals, 'r-', color=colors[str(year)],    label=str(year), alpha=0.4)
fig.set_size_inches((14,10))
fig.set_dpi(800)

ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsFmt)

plt.savefig('sick_pick.png')
```

It makes a graph looking something like

[image: decent looking matplotlib!]

In my case I have a pre-existing dictionary of dataframes where each is accessed by year as the key. Saving to PDF is possible, saving to PNG image file is easier I think as shown above the plt.savefig('filename.png') should work. The PDF functionality is definitely cool. I've had nagging clients (with no clue what they are talking about) ask for reports/charts etc. You can set up a loop and write a PDF with hundreds and thousands of pages where each page is a nicely formatted chart with a title, legend, axis labels etc. Traditionally the complaint against matplotlib was the dry and generic looking graphs. The new matplotlib styles are very easy on the eye!

EDIT:
Check this awesome answer to solve your legend issues. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701285/2639868